# How to get last page (local or not) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried:

```
console.log( document.referrer );
```

But it only works for *"http://"*

---

I need it to work with *"file://"* ... How can I do it?

Comment: Run a local server, access via the _http_ protocol instead of _file_ protocol.

Comment: @PaulS. Changing "file://" to another protocol isn't an option in this particular case

Comment: It looks like you might be working locally? You'll need to upload your file(s) to a server - then your path will contain `http` and not `file`. If you are actually downloading a file (pdf or something) you could take what info you are given with `document.referrer` and manipulate it - to create your own uri. For example, create a new string and replace `http` with `file` then return that to whatever you need.

Comment: @dragonslovetacos It will run in an iPad app that simulate a browser, but locally... In other words: if document.referrer don't work, what would work locally?

Comment: Will all the pages that you use be local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the pages are local, you could use JavaScript to set a cookie or use the HTML5 local storage to save and retrieve the referrer.

One example using the localStorage object. Add this code to all your pages:

```
// get the referrer if it's set
var referrer = "";
if (localStorage.getItem("referrer")) {
    referrer = localStorage.getItem("referrer");
}

// set the new referrer 
localStorage.setItem("referrer", window.location.href);

// show the previous page url (just for testing)
console.log(referrer);
```

Comment: That's nice! ...Thanks =)